# html select tag not working in django template

Tags: html, django, django-templates

This question is asked many times, but I think I am having issues with strings in the Django template

I have a select tag and I want to select the default option from database

```
    <select name="category" class="form-control" required="" id="id_category">
     <option value="" >--------</option>
     {% for cat in all_categories %}
     <option value="{{cat}}" {% if form.instance.category == cat %} selected {% endif %}> {{cat}}</option>
     {% endfor %}                        
    </select>
```

my {{cat}} variable has value 'Django Book' and {{form.instance.category}} also have same value i.e. 'Django Book'.

But it doesn't select the desired option

however, I am using similar logic in another part

```
<select class="form-control" id="client" required name="client">
  <option value=" ">-----</option>
  {% for customer in all_customers %}
  <option value="{{customer.pk}}" {% if form.instance.client_id.pk == customer.pk %}selected{% endif %}>{{customer}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

but this time I am comparing ids to select the default option and it works.

what is the issue in the above code?? is this issue with strings?? and how can I overcome this.

Also, I would like to set strings in the value attribute in the first code example.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: String comparison is quite straightforward in templates too, so I do not think it is the problem. The majority of problems of this kind come from typos or wrong data in variables. So, I would recommend putting some debug data, like `form.instance.category is [{{form.instance.category}}]` before select tag, and then you inspect values of options of select tag in the "inspect" elements of your browser.

Comment: @datosula, I tried `form.instance.category is [{{form.instance.category}}]` and it is giving the exact same string as it is in the `value` in the select tag, I also double-checked for typos, and data is stored in CharField in my model
but still, it is not selecting the right option

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

create a `templatetags` folder inside the app. And create two file inside that folder i.e `__init__.py` & `filters.py`.

let the `__init__` file be empty and write the filter code inside the `filters` file.

```
from django.template import Library

register = Library()

@register(name='string_filter')
def string_filter(value1, *args, **kwargs):
    if args:
       value2 = args[0].lower()
       if value2 == value1.lower():
          return True
       else:
          return False
    else:
       return False
```

Now load the filter into your template at top of the file but below `{% load static %}`

```
{% load 'filters' %}
```

Now user the filter into the select tag.

```
<select name="category" class="form-control" required="" id="id_category">
   <option value="" >--------</option>
   {% for cat in all_categories %}
      {% if form.instance.category|string_filter: cat %}
   <option value="{{cat}}" selected> {{cat}}</option>
      {% else %}
   <option value="{{cat}}"> {{cat}}</option>
      {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}                        
</select>
```

Comment: I am having an issue in the category select box in comparing strings, not in this one, this select box is already working fine

Comment: i tried this but it is giving me ``Could not parse the remainder: ':' from 'form.instance.category|string_filter:'``


in `{% if form.instance.category|string_filter: cat %}` this line